# Why does my column chart show 100% for each category that I want to show?

Tags: graph, powerbi, dax, report, visualization

I am trying to create a bar and line chart, for the bar chart, I want to show the split between Complete and Incomplete ( my categories) in %, however, my bar chart is showing me 100% for both categories and the total bar adds up to 200%. I want to create a 100% stacked bar chart that will show me the split between Complete and Incomplete

[image: Bar Chart showing 200%]

This is the code for this measure I wrote:

```
Measure try =
Var Total = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[Install Base]), FILTER('PM Checklist vs Last SP Used','PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[PM Complete?] = "Complete")) + CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[Install Base]), FILTER('PM Checklist vs Last SP Used','PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[PM Complete?] = "Incomplete"))
Return DIVIDE(DISTINCTCOUNT('PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[Install Base]),Total)
```

I placed this measure under Values, hoping that my Legend Field can help me distinguish those that are complete vs incomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `var Total` is being filtered too. Try:

```
var total =
  CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[Install Base]),
    REMOVEFILTERS('PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[PM Complete?])
  )
```

Comment: However, If I add a filter to this page, by excluding blank date columns, my values will go over 100% ... why do you think this happened?